# Priority in DB2

Tags: group-by, db2

This is my Parent_Child Table.

```
PARENT  CHILD   TOT_BAL_AMT EFF_DT  END_DT      REFN_ID
22716   2528    5632    3/2/2015    3/5/2015    4112
22716   5698    5632    3/2/2015    5/9/2014    2563
22716   3256    5896    5/6/2014    5/6/2013    4555
37091   7412    4563    5/6/2015    1/1/2015    5666
37091   9632    4563    3/25/2015   2/5/2015    7896
425696  25      9000    3/8/2014    1/1/2015    45174
425696  30      8000    9/9/2015    1/1/2014    20000
```

The expected result for this table is like this
Select Refn_Id for Parent, child combination by the following priorities:

- **Priority 1-** Pickup the **Refn_id** for which **Tot_Bal** is maximum. If there is tie then
- **Priority 2-** Pickup the Refn_Id for which EFf_Dt is maximum. If there is tie then
- **Priority 3-** Pickup the Refn_Id for the latest End_Dt.

So this is the output

```
PARENT  CHILD   REFN_ID
22716   2528    4112
37091   7412    5666
425696  25      45174
```

Is it possible to write a single query in DB2 for this?If not is it possible to write a stored procedure.
PS: I don't have experience writing Stored Procedure.
Appreciate any help

Comment: I would *expect* the answer to be:  "no, not as a single query."  Basically, what the query-engine can do is to provide you with all of the related-records that *could* match, all neatly-organized into GROUPs.  This is, therefore, a *set* of records from which your logic must now choose, group-by-group.  A stored-procedure might be able to incorporate such logic, but "a database-engine is not necessarily a great place to put *a computer-program."*

Comment: Why do you select refn_id = 4112 for parent = 22716? The total_balance for ref_id = 4555 is higher (4555) than the one for refn_id = 4112 (which is only 5632). If that is a typo in your expected toutput, this can easily be solved using window functions: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/70b10/1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes its a typo actually 4555 should be selected

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks a lot!! didnt knew row_number() works this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done using window functions:

```
select *
from (
  select pc.*,
         row_number() over (partition by parent order by tot_bal_amt desc, eff_dt desc, end_dt desc) as rn
  from parent_child pc
) t
where rn = 1
order by parent;
```

SQLFiddle example (using Postgres): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/70b10/2

For each parent, the rows are numbered based on the priorities you have defined. And the row with the number 1 is the one (for each parent) that you are interested in. To see what exactly the `row_number()` does, just run the inner select on its own.

If you are new to window functions, consider this presentation: http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2015-02/modern-sql  (starting at slide 65)